# обновление контента без перезагрузки

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

у меня есть файл stat.dat в котором есть цыфра и вызываеться include "stat.dat";
как сделать что бы имненно этот блок div обновлялся каждые например 10 секунд (блоков будет много)

Comment: это если что кол-во просмотров которое знесено в файл

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval / http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: На чистом JS? Или JQuery ?

Comment: пофиг как-то...

Answer (score 1):

Если используете JQuery то как-то так :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 10000);

    function myCallback() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "index.php",
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'POST',
        }).done(function (data) {

            $("#divId").text(data);

        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
        });

    }
}
```

на стороне сервера:

```
   $filePath = "путь к файлу/stat.dat";
   if (file_exists($filePath)) 
        echo file_get_contents();
   else
        echo 0;
```